# Simple Prolog Hangman game error

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

I am trying to develop a simple hangman game as a homework for a subject in university. It is very simples but I am having trouble and I am unable to make it work.

This the code:

```
member(El,[El|_]).
member(El,[_|Tl]) :- member(El,Tl).

inc(X,Y) :- Y is X+1.
dec(X,Y) :- Y is X-1.

start(E,A) :-
    ((E==5) -> loose,!);
    ((A==3) -> won,!);
    nl,
    write('write a letter: '),
    read(Letter),
    (member(Letter,[c,a,r])>write('Hit!'),inc(A,W), 
    start(E,W);write('Miss!'),inc(E,L),start(L,A)).

loose :- write(‘You Loose !!!').
won :- write(‘You Win!!!').
```

The idea of the game is for the player try to guess the word "car", that i put in a list [c,a,r]. when the player types  a letter that is in the list, A=A+1. when the player types  a letter that is not in the list, E=E+1. It should repeat itself until A=3 (Player won) or E=5 (Player lost = 5 wrong letters). But it is not working as it should. And the program never is able to repet the loop to the palyer win or loose the game.

when I put a valid letter, I got this message:

```
?- start(E,A).
write a letter: a.
Hit!
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [10] _4366 is _4372+1
ERROR:    [8] start(_4398,_4400) at c:/users/documents/prolog/new2.pl:7
ERROR:    [7] <user>
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

when I put an invalid letter, I got the same message:

```
?- start(E,A).
write a letter: k.
Miss!
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [10] _5378 is _5384+1
ERROR:    [8] start(_5410,_5412) at c:/users/ocuments/prolog/new2.pl:7
ERROR:    [7] <user>
ERROR: 
ERROR: Note: some frames are missing due to last-call optimization.
ERROR: Re-run your program in debug mode (:- debug.) to get more detail.
```

Please, could someome more experienced in Prolog help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `Y is X+1` and `Y is X-1` each requires that `X` be instantiated. Otherwise, `is` cannot evaluate the expression. Specifically, `inc(X, Y)` is being called with `X` not having a value.

Comment: Hi lurker, thanks a lot for your answer. I understand what you said and I tried to solve the problem but I am being successful. I mind it is still bounded to imperative languages, so my natural thought was X=0 and obviously it didn't worked.


Could you please help me to instantiate the X variable?

I already tried theese options and searched on the internet, without success until now:

1)X=0.
2)X is 0.
3) inc(X=0,Y) :- Y is X+1.
4)X=0. (terminal).

Comment: By what I read about variables in Prolog, the instantiton of X must be inside this rule (inc(X,Y) :- Y is X+1.), right? I just do not know what to do to instantiate it.

Comment: When you call `inc(A, W)`, then `A` must be instantiated for the call. If you write, `X = 0, inc(X, Y).` you should see a result. If you write `X is 0, inc(X, Y).` you should see a result. `inc(X=0, Y)` would not be valid since you'd then be writing `Y is (X=0)+1` which is an invalid expression.

Comment: Hello lurker, thanks for your answer. I did what you said and I learned somethings more. As you said, the program showed a result and I got another error, please, see my answer. I would appreciate if you could help me.